# Disable go modules caching via pkg.go.dev

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm really struggling with go modules. The cache in https://pkg.go.dev/ seems to be everlasting with no way to clear the cache. If you change from a monorepo with multiple go modules there's no way to update to one go.mod in the root.

For example if you add github.com/web-ridge/gqlgen-sqlboiler/v2/boiler as import it will keep referencing to https://pkg.go.dev/mod/github.com/web-ridge/gqlgen-sqlboiler/boiler@v0.0.0-20200424102639-0c95b5d41c2c?tab=packages while it should be referencing to the root.

I've moved all my directories to the root to workaround this issue: https://github.com/web-ridge/gqlgen-sqlboiler.

And also when I run go mod tidy it add github.com/gertd/go-pluralize v0.1.4 while that's not the case anymore on GitHub, but still is https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gertd/go-pluralize@v0.1.4?tab=doc.

Is there some way to disable pkg.go.dev or let them refresh libraries?

Comment: If you've changed from multiple modules to a single module, that's a breaking change and should have been published as v2.0.0, which should avoid any issues with pkg.go.dev.

Comment: Ah ok! I did change to v2 as go module but not as a GitHub tag. What about the go pluralize I think they did rewrite the git history or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the help I think I understand go modules and versioning more now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To update the version's cache of your package in [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev) then save this command to a Makefile or a task manager you are using:

```
update-pkg-cache:
 GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org GO111MODULE=on \
 go get github.com/$(USER)/$(PACKAGE)@v$(VERSION)
```

Now run the following command i.e.

```sh
$ make update-pkg-cache USER=gertd PACKAGE=go-pluralize VERSION=1.16.3
```

- `USER` is your GitHub user name or organization name.
- `PACKAGE` is the name of your package to update the cache.
- `VERSION` is a version number to update the cache.